# Ruby on rails: URL from ids to names/titles etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created model objects of from generating a scaffold, but now I want to instead of linking to
/:controller/:id (/objectname/1) to /:controller/:title (/objectname/new_blog_post). How do I do this so that links will correct link to the title and not id?

I want to go from:

```
/:controller/:id
```

to

```
/:controller/:name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use to param

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    name.blank? ? id : name
  end

end
```

Or look into a plugin, acts_as_sluggable and friendly_id are ones I know of.

EDIT: Oh yes and as mentioned make sure whatever you use is unique.

EDIT:

it would work like:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

end
```

In view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user_path(@user.id) %>
<% end %>
```

And if the that users name is John then it will render /users/John after you click that link

Comment: +1 You know, I've never overridden `to_param`. Maybe I should start doing that.

Comment: Actually, looking at that again, would that be a good idea? If name were blank, what would his finds look like in the controller?

Comment: It is still find with an id, the blank check it to put the id as the url if there is no name. It's untested but it demonstrates a basic idea for it.

Comment: I guess my point was more directed at if he were to do something like what you suggested above, he should at least validate the presence of a name, rendering the id part useless because his finds will be `find_by_name` as opposed to just `find`. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You still find by id. It just renders a name as the url for that object if the name exists, otherwise it uses the id as normal.

Comment: I had not understood that. That's awesome, thanks for the tip.

Comment: How to you find by id if you can only have the name from the request url?

IMO the best option is to have a separate field for the slug.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change a few things:

You'll have to pass the `title` attribute to any paths/urls when you do stuff like `link_to` e.g.

```
post_path(@post)
```

will become

```
post_path(@post.title)
```

You'll also have to update your finds to look for posts by title, as opposed to id e.g.

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

will become

```
@post = Post.find_by_title(params[:title])
```

That should get you started :). You'll obviously want to slug the title and validate the uniqueness of the title as well.

EDIT: After reading Robert Elwell's answer, maybe I misunderstood the question. Do you already have a route like you described for a specific object, or are you doing this with the 'basic' routes? If the latter, you're much better off writing a custom route like Robert suggests, and then doing some of the stuff I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Write a [custom route](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use friendly_id.

BTW, generating url isn't working for me. I had written my own to the model

```
def to_param
  self.friendly_id
end
```